# Browsers issues

Tags: css, cross-browser

I am having a cross browser problem with IE 7 and I have decided to go for a different style sheet for it. Could you please advise me what is the best way to call IE7 when used? And keep of course the other one for all the other browser. Many thanks Francesco

Comment: Just to add my two cents, I like to make sure my HTML / CSS  is valid, and that I am using a reset.css before launching into conditional comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link href="/ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Hurray for conditional comments! No need for ugly hacks, and there is almost always a chance to make all other browsers behave with valid CSS.

Answer (score 2):

[Conditional Comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)